# How to deserialise Json object into android class?

Tags: android, json

I have JSON object like "{ FirstName: Sergey, LastName: Petrov, Sex: Male }"

And I have class with these names in the android application.

How to deserialize this JSON object into class in the android applications.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options, i recomend you this one: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Maybe we have some build in libraries?